# Hub and Spoke indication using Python

Tags: python

## Situation

Our company generates waste from various locations in US. The waste is taken to different locations based on suppliers' treatment methods and facilities placed nationally.
Consider a waste stream A which is being generated from location X. Now  the overall costs to take care of Stream A includes Transportation cost from our site as well treatment method. This data is tabulated.

## What I want to achieve

I would like my python program to import excel table containing this data and plot the distance between our facility and treatment facility and also show in a hub-spoke type picture just like airlines do as well show data regarding treatment method as a color or something just like on google maps.

Can someone give me leads on where should I start or which python API or module that might best suite my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather broad question and perhaps not the best for SO.
Now to answer it: you can read excel's csv files with the `csv` module. Plotting is best done with `matplotlib.pyplot`.